# Pandas read "delimited" file

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter

[image]

Hi, I have such .txt file, with the first column represent index, which is followed by three columns inside a pair of "()" representing x, y and z coordinates.

I want to load the first four columns of this file to pandas Dataframe. However, I found it's pretty hard as the delimiter is firstly " " and then "(" and inside the parenthesis there is ",".

Could someone give me some hint on how to deal with such situation?

Thank you!
Shawn

Comment: Please don't post data as pictures.  We can not cut and paste a picture.

Comment: Sorry, the file is shared at:https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy95y4z3lzws5c6/Initial_Coordinate.txt?dl=0

Comment: I don't do dropbox, it is a security risk.  Please data in the post.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551662/import-text-to-pandas-with-multiple-delimiters/26551913) for ways to read in a file with multiple delimiters and check out the `usecols` keyword argument in [the docs for the `read_csv` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write your own parser.  Something like:

**Code:**

```
def parse_my_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield [x.strip(',()')
                   for x in re.split(r'\s+', line.strip())[:4]]
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(parse_my_file('file1'))
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
    0       1       2  3
0  g1     -16       0  0
1  gr      10       0  0
2  D1  -6.858  2.7432  0
3  D2  -2.286  2.7432  0
```

This data file was created when I typed in your first four rows.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your parser rule and it works great! tell k reminded me of not using complicated delimiters and even though I don't know why, but I think your solution directs me on the track! I need to look more deeper into your func. Thank you again!

Comment: @DarthBEHFANS
, you are very welcome.  However, on SO the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex pattern` as seperator of CSV.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Initial_Coordinate.txt', sep=r'[()]', header=None)
print(df)
```

However, rather than creating complex delimiters, it is better to fix it as a simple delimiter and then read it with pandas.

thx

Comment: Thanks! I tried the sep=r'[(,)]' and it works. May I ask what is the '[]' for in regex pattern? And your comment on "fix it as a simple delimiter", does it mean create some parser rule and substitute certain delimiters with uniform delimiter?

Comment: @DarthBEHFANS "[]" is metacharacter of regex.  It means that it matches either of the two characters '(' and ')'. see also https://help.kcura.com/9.0/Content/Relativity/Regular_expressions/Regular_expression_metacharacters.htm

Comment: @DarthBEHFANS > does it mean create some parser rule and substitute certain delimiters with uniform delimiter? 

No, it is not. 
I mean that it is better to convert the original file (Initial_Coordinate.txt) to a simple delimiter. for example tab character.