# Unable to read a .txt file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to read a .txt file using pandas the output I get is all the rows and columns with `NaN`. The text file has multiple delimiters.

I tried `sep = 's+'` and sep `'\t'` and still I get `NaN` for all the values.

Output:

[image: example output]

Input:
[image: example input]

Comment: Can you give an example input file and some simple code showing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show how you are you loading this data as well as a sample of the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import text to pandas with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551662/import-text-to-pandas-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("file location url",names=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'], sep= '\s+')

Comment: Can someone help me read the input using pandas ?