# Separating read_csv by multiple parameters

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I’ve imported a txt file using read_csv and I need to separate it by multiple parameters. So far all I’ve done is:

‘’’

```
 df = pd.read_csv(file name, header=None, sep = ‘\n’)
```

However along with separating it at the new lines I also need to separate by both a comma and an underscore. How could I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import text to pandas with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551662/import-text-to-pandas-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: Can you add an example input line and what the result should be?

Comment: You are using *fancy* quotes in shown code, you do not show first lines of the csv file to help others to understand the question and you do not show the expected output. Without a [mcve] you could only guess. You should read again [ask]...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on format of the data, but You may try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep='\_|,', engine='python')
```

When `engine` is set to "python" you can use regular expressions in `sep` argument.